# Ignore errors in an Observable<Single<T>>

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an `Observable<Single<T>>` that I would like to transform that to a new `Observable<T>` where any `Single<T>` that fails is ignored.

Here is my attempt at an implementation:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> skipErrors(final Observable<Single<T>> xs) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(xs);
    return xs.flatMap(single -> single.map(Optional::of)
        .onErrorReturn(error -> Optional.empty())
        .flatMapObservable(optional ->
            optional.map(Observable::just).orElseGet(Observable::empty)));
}
```

Basically it wraps every success in an `Optional` and maps every failure to `Optional.empty()`. The optionals are then filtered in a `flatMapObservable`.

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

---

Unit-test:

```
final Observable<Single<String>> observable = skipErrors(Observable.just(
    Single.error(new Exception()),
    Single.error(new Exception()),
    Single.just("Hello"),
    Single.error(new Exception()),
    Single.just("world"),
    Single.error(new Exception())));

final ImmutableList<String> expected = ImmutableList.of("Hello", "world");
final ImmutableList<String> actual = observable.toList()
    .blockingGet()
    .stream()
    .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());

assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it a bit simpler:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> skipErrors(final Observable<Single<T>> singles) {
  Preconditions.checkNotNull(xs);
  return singles
    .flatMap(single -> single
        .toObservable()
        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
    );
}
```

Comment: That is indeed simpler. Thanks!